# Srednicki - computing divergent piece of loop integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, trace, dimensional-regularization

I was reading through Srednicki and didn't quite understand one of the paragraphs in Section $51$ on loop corrections in the Yukawa theory on P.$322$. It's the fermion loop correction to the local four point vertex interaction - the numerator is a horrendous trace but he says that to compute the divergent contribution one can send all of the external momenta to zero, $k_i \rightarrow 0$. Why is this so? Is it just because the divergency occurs in the far UV so at this energy scale, the internal route momentum greatly exceeds any other scale in the problem?

Upon doing this, he says the only contribution is then $4(\ell^2)^2$ to the trace. Since $$\text{Tr}(( \not l + m)( \not l + m)( \not l + m)( \not l + m)) = 4(l^4 + 6m^2l^2 + m^4)$$ ignoring terms odd in $l$ which vanish under symmetric integration. So I get the $4l^2$ term he mentions but I have additional terms. Is he again just neglecting them because to get the divergent piece we can neglect all other scales? Assuming this is true, I get the integral $$4g^4 \int \frac{d^D l}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{l^4}{(l^2-m^2)^4}$$ Since $[g] = \mu^{\epsilon}$, I can rewrite the coupling and then use $$\mu^{2 \epsilon} \int \frac{d^D l}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{(l^2)^2}{(l^2-m^2)^4} = \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{D/2}} iD(D+2) \frac{\Gamma(4-D/2-2)}{\Gamma(4)} \left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)^{4-D/2-2}$$ And in the text there are 6 possible permutations of the momenta so is it a case of just multiplying this result by 6?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104899/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question asks why in the computation of the divergent part of MS 51.49, we can set $k_i=0$.

To see this, we do an intuitive counting of the power of $l$ in the integrals. Notice each fermion propagator effectively contributes $\frac{1}{l^4}$ and the integral measure $d^4l\sim l^3dl$, so it is $\frac{1}{l}$ divergent at large $l$. Thus if one subtracts the leading $l$ piece from the numerator, one gets at least $\frac{1}{l^2}$ UV behaviour for large $l$ and thus is safe from UV divergence, i.e. (to illustrate the point, I omit the $\gamma_5$'s)

$$\begin{align}
&\small\int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{Tr( \not l(\not l-k_1)(\not l+\not k_2+\not k_3)(\not l+\not k_2) )}{(l^2+m^2)((l-k_1)^2+m^2)((l+k_2+k_3)^2+m^2)((l+k_2)^2+m^2)}-\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{Tr( \not l\not l\not l\not l )}{(l^2+m^2)^4}
\\=&\int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{N'}{(l^2+m^4)^4((l-k_1)^2+m^2)((l+k_2+k_3)^2+m^2)((l+k_2)^2+m^2)}
\end{align}$$

where $$\begin{align}
N'=&Tr( \not l(\not l-k_1)(\not l+\not k_2+\not k_3)(\not l+\not k_2) )(l^2+m^2)^3-\\&Tr( \not l\not l\not l\not l )((l-k_1)^2+m^2)((l+k_2+k_3)^2+m^2)((l+k_2)^2+m^2)=O(l^9).
\end{align}$$

Thus for large $l$ the above behaves as $\sim \int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{l^9}{l^{14}}\sim\int dl \frac{l^{12}}{l^{14}}\sim\int dl\frac{1}{l^2}$ which is UV finite. 
Therefore, to compute the UV divergent piece, one only needs to compute the leading term in the numerator, i.e.

$$\int\frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{Tr( \not l\not l\not l\not l )}{(l^2+m^2)^4}$$, which contains the UV divergence. 
 Setting $k_i=0$, and picking the leading term in $l$ effectively gives one the leading $l$ term in the numerator. This also clarifies your second question.

For the third question, yes, just multiply the result by 6, as they give identical contributions.

There is one comment that I would like to make. The above explanation should really be understood with proper UV cut off- it does not make sense to do algebraic manipulations on divergent integrals! To give a fully rigorous argument on why it is enough to just consider the leading $l$ terms in the numerator, one needs to use some UV cut off, and subtract the integral with only the leading term from the full expression and then show it is bounded as the cut off goes to infinity.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Could you explain what you mean by 'Thus if one subtracts the leading $l$ piece from the numerator, one gets at least $1/l^2$ UV behaviour for large $l$ and thus is safe from UV divergence'?

Comment: @CAF sure I can write it more explicitly

Comment: Ok thanks for the edit! Also in Srednicki he writes that the contribution $iV_{4, \Psi}$ (51.50) is of the same sign as the term in $Z_{\lambda}$ (51.53) .This seems wrong to me because the whole point of $Z_{\lambda}$ in $\bar{MS}$ is solely to remove the divergent pole in $\epsilon$  so it should come with an opposite sign no?

Comment: @CAF Not quite. Look at MS 51.52; $Z_{\lambda}$ has minus sign before it

Comment: I see. But it is confusing because in my lecture notes, we use the convention that the tree level contribution is $iZ_{\lambda}\lambda$ whereas here it is $-iZ_{\lambda}\lambda$. I don't see how these differences can be resolved.

Comment: Actually I might be mistaken there indeed. Do you know why in $\phi^3$ theories the interaction term is written $+g/3! \phi^3$ while for $\phi^4$ theories it is $-\lambda/4! \phi^4$? This change of sign is crucial here I suppose.

Comment: @CAF You can feel free to replace $g$ by $-g$ or $-\lambda$ by $\lambda$. It is just convention

Comment: Ah but the choice dictates what the feynman rule will be though yes? So if srednicki and I agree on writing our theory with $-\lambda$ then we should both have negative in our feynman rules (if I understand correctly). Also,  do you know the source of the minus sign that must be included for fermion loops in these integrals? Thanks!  I +1 and accepted

Comment: @CAF Yes Feynman rules depend on the specific interacting term you add so once the interacting term is specified, say $\frac{1}{6}g\phi^3$ or $-\frac{1}{6}g\phi^3$, you would have the corresponding Feynman rules (vertex rule:$ig$ or $-ig$ respectively). The minus sign is a relatively long story and it might be worthwhile to ask a new question for that.

Comment: Hi, I just realised a possible mistake in what you wrote, $N'$ goes as $\mathcal O(l^{10})$ not $\mathcal O(l^9)$ so it seems the argument no longer works?

Comment: @CAF No the highest order terms cancel. They are both given by $Tr(\not l\not l\not l\not l)l^6$. So it is $O(l^9)$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - $$\text{Tr}(\not l \not l \not  l \not l) \propto l^4$$ so $\text{Tr}(\not l \not l \not  l \not l)l^6 \propto l^{10}?$$

Comment: @CAF Yep; Specifically you can try to see that by noticing $\not l \not l =-4l^2$

Comment: Ok, so that means that $\text{Tr}(\not l \not l \not l \not l)l^6 \propto l^{10}$ no? and therefore $N'$ scales as $\mathcal O(l^{10})$?

Comment: Yeah. By the way, I made a typo in the last comment. It should be $tr(\not l \not l)=-4l^2$; $\not l\not l =-l^2$. But yes what you said is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks,  So how to address my question in my original post?

Comment: @CAF Which one?

Comment: I want to know why when we send $k_i \rightarrow 0$, we obtain the divergent piece of the original integral. Your method of showing that the original integral minus the piece where all the k's are zero is UV finite seems to imply to me that the divergency lies in the latter term. However, when we proceed with the math we find such a subtraction is still uv divergent (because the numerator is order $l^{10}$ and not 9 as said previously) . So I'm a little confused.

Comment: @CAF When we set $k_i\to 0$ we obtain a term that contains the divergent piece of the original integral which is the term I wrote in my answer. (modulo I didn't include $\gamma_5$). $N'\sim O(l^9)$ not $l^{10}$: the $l^{10}$ pieces cancel with each other and that is the point of doing the subtraction. The expression of $N'$ contains two lines if that is where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, so basically we have a sum like $$\mathcal O(l^{10}) + \mathcal O (l^9 m) + \mathcal O(l^8 m^2 ) + ..$$ and the leading term cancels with the term that is subtracted